# Global/European maximum daily temperature forecast

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am searching for either **global** or **preferably European maximum daily temperature forecasts** (I don't care for any historic data). To give you an example:

- I wake up in the morning and want to know the **maximum temperature** for today and for the next three days. For my application it would be best if the data is in any kind of **GIS or geographic data format.** I tried searching the ECMWF but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

The following are some related and useful databases/ links:

- [European data portal](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/datasets?locale=en&tags=weather&keywords=weather)
- [Global and European temperature](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/indicators/global-and-european-temperature-9/assessment)
- [International Research Institute for Climate & Society Data Library](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu) :  There are over 400 climate-related datasets there. It is possible to analyze the data on-line, make graphics, and refer easily back to those through the URLs. The data can be saved in many formats, including GIS, and read directly into software such as MATLAB.
  There is a little bit of a learning curve, but it is very powerful. Tutorials can help if you are new to it.
- [What is the best data center to download world climatic data?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_data_center_to_download_world_climatic_data)

---